# How can Apache be installed in a OpenVZ container

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, openvz

I have OPenVZ running on CentOS and a precreated Ubuntu 10.04 OS template installed.The containers created have 2GB of disk space allocated.With this,can I have an Apache web server running within a container, where I can host a website.Will this site then be accesible to other container users?If so how do I proceed?

Comment: Of course you can install apache inside an OpenVZ container, you might want to go back and read the manual a bit, if you're not sure about how networking works in OpenVZ.

Comment: @NickW Are the steps similar to installing Apache in Centos?Will the template being Ubuntu matter?

Comment: Yes, inside the OpenVZ container, the OS functions just like a normal one, only the network devices are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it is near impossible to install/operate an Apache service on a 2GB OpenVZ container. The main reason for this consideration will be the available allocation space for the following (based on the notion that your container will be flagged for production usage):

- Binaries
- Log Files
- Libraries
- Modules

On top of that, the container will also require storage space for the primary template-related binaries to be stored in, and that itself will consume the allocated 2GB storage space within the OpenVZ container.

---

Moving forward, I would like to encourage you to consider increasing the allocated storage space to approximately 10GB (if you have adequate system resources) or more. That will provide you with the necessary storage space to install Apache, and any other relevant modules properly without worrying about sufficient storage space within the container.

You can safely ignore the above if the OpenVZ container in-concern is flagged for development purposes.

I do hope that you will find the above information useful.

Comment: Thanks,that's indeed informative.Well,this is actually for demonstration purpose,i would eventually want to have website running,and demonstrate that any security threat to the web server by a malicious user would not affect other user's session.

Comment: if it is meant for dev/demo purposes, then you are all set for a 2GB container. :)